# Tensorflow lite - depth map - based on stereo vision

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite, disparity-mapping

I have not found any project, library, model or guide to measure distance using stereo imaging with tensorflow lite 2.

I want to be able to measure distance from stereo images.
I would like to be able to run it on android, so I would like to create a model in tensorflow 2 or use an existing one. But I don't know where to start, everything I found uses pytorch

I know that opencv provides a method to do it, but according to the literature neural networks achieve better results. But I have not found any model in tensorflow 2.
I can't use google ar, because my device doesn't support google play services.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/datvuthanh/Stereo-Matching

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately the project uses operator operators outside the definition of the model, to perform the inference, (such as tf.reduce_sum and tf.multiply).
It is my understanding that there is no direct implementation in TFLite of such operators, I think it is not a very good option :(

Comment: FYI, tf.reduce_sum and tf.multiply are supported in TFLite builtin ops.

Comment: I understand that they are operations supported by the interpreter with an exported model.
But the project uses them outside the definition of the model.
I could not instantiate any of these operations from the libraries within the namespace tensorflow-lite. https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/op_select_allowlist

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand the meaning of the 'outside the definition of the model'. Could you share the conversion error message?

Comment: for example, this line when he makes an inference https://github.com/datvuthanh/Stereo-Matching/blob/33f9f391a298e0cd43822b2e29a9dbf5a4fc318b/inference.py#L122 in this case, the model is purely convolutional. The rest of the calculation is done outside the model

Comment: There is possibility that the above inference code can be turned into a single TF model by using tf.function or the TF model serialization. It requires some more coding for that. You may ask the github owner for a feature request.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I will investigate how to include it within the model with tf.function.

Answer (score 1):

I have just uploaded a repository for this purpose:
https://github.com/ibaiGorordo/TFLite-HITNET-Stereo-depth-estimation

It uses the stereo depth estimation HITNET model (from Google-Research) converted to tensorflow lite by @PINTO0309 (find the models here: https://github.com/PINTO0309/PINTO_model_zoo/tree/main/142_HITNET)

Comment: great job! Thank you so much for sharing it